# Python -- get at JSON info that's written like XML

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing, urllib2

In Python, I usually do simple JSON with this sort of template:

```
url = "url"
file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
json = file.read()
parsed = json.loads(json)
```

and then get at the variables with calls like:

```
parsed[obj name][value name]
```

But, this works with JSON that's formatted roughly like:

```
{'object':{'index':'value', 'index':'value'}}
```

The JSON I just encountered is formatted like:

```
{'index':'value', 'index':'value'},{'index':'value', 'index':'value'}
```

so there are no names for me to reference the different blocks.  Of course the blocks give different info, but have the same "keys" -- much like XML is usually formatted.  Using my method above, how would I parse through this JSON?

Comment: It is, I just didn't include the brackets.  Now that you mention that, lists are numerated indexes, so it occurs to me that I could use number indexes like json[1]['index'].  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not a valid JSON.

`{'index':'value', 'index':'value'},{'index':'value', 'index':'value'}`

Where as

`[{'index':'value', 'index':'value'},{'index':'value', 'index':'value'}]` is a valid JSON.

and python trackback shows that

```
import json
string = "{'index':'value', 'index':'value'},{'index':'value', 'index':'value'}"
parsed = json.loads(string)
print parsed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tron/Desktop/test3.py", line 3, in <module>
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 27 - line 1 column 54 (char 26 - 53)
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

where is if you do

```
json_string = '[{"a":"value", "b":"value"},{"a":"value", "b":"value"}]'
```

everything works fine.

If that is the case, you can refer to it as an array of Jsons. where `json_string[0]` is the first JSON string. `json_string[1]` is the second and so on.

Otherwise if you think this is going to be an issue that you "just have to deal with". Here is one option:

Think of the ways JSON can be malformed and write a simple class to account for them. In the case above, here is a hacky way you can deal with it.

```
import json
json_string = '{"a":"value", "b":"value"},{"a":"value", "b":"value"}'
def parseJson(string):
    parsed_json = None
    try:
        parsed_json = json.loads(string)
        print parsed_json
    except ValueError, e:
        print string, "didnt parse"
        if  "Extra data" in str(e.args):
            newString = "["+string+"]"
            print newString
            return parseJson(newString)
```

You could add more if/else to deal with various things you run into. I have to admit, this is very hacky and I don't think you can ever account for *every* possible mutation.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The result must be `list` of `dict`:

```
[{'index1':'value1', 'index2':'value2'},{'index1':'value1', 'index2':'value2'}]
```

thus you can reference it using numbers: `item[1]['index1']`